# Issue Understanding SQL Server Merge for Bulk Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, merge, bulkinsert

I generate a `DataTable` and I first remove all rows from that `DataTable` in C#.

Then I pass on the DataTable to a stored procedure for the bulk insert but I am getting error randomly stating:

> The Merge statement updated /delete same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row.

But what is confusing me is I remove all duplicate rows from the DataTable before sending it to the stored procedure.

CODE:

```
public static DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string colName)
{
    Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
    ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();

    //Add list of all the unique item value to hashtable, which stores combination of key, value pair.
    //And add duplicate item value in arraylist.
    foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
    {
        if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
            duplicateList.Add(drow);
        else
            hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty);
    }

    //Removing a list of duplicate items from datatable.
    foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
        dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);

    //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
    return dTable;
}
```

And this is the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_DataFeed_Discoverable]
  @tblCustomers DateFeed_Discoverable READONLY
  AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  MERGE INTO DataFeed c1
  USING @tblCustomers c2
  ON c1.CheckSumProductName=checksum(c2.aw_deep_link)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET 
        c1.merchant_name = c2.merchant_name
        ,c1.aw_deep_link = c2.aw_deep_link
        ,c1.brand_name = c2.brand_name
        ,c1.product_name = c2.product_name
        ,c1.merchant_image_url = c2.merchant_image_url
        ,c1.Price = c2.Price

  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT VALUES(c2.merchant_name, c2.aw_deep_link,
  c2.brand_name, c2.product_name, c2.merchant_image_url,
  c2.Price,1,checksum(c2.aw_deep_link)

  );
END
```

So does it end up with duplicate rows when they are not Inserted and removed before using the DataTable.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The expression `checksum(c2.aw_deep_link)` is returning the same value for more than one value of `c2.aw_deep_link` so it's matching certain `DataFeed` rows multiple times. `MERGE` effectively does a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between the two tables and performs different actions based on whether the target, source, or both contain rows in the result. When the target matches multiple rows in the source, that's what causes that error. You'll need to figure out how to get a 1:1 match for every source row in the target table.

Comment: Or there are two rows in the DataTable with the same aw_deep_link.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft how can it bee when i remove duplicates before sending it to the procedure using the above function..